# MySQL Syntax error near ' ' at line 1

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have reviewed it several times, and I'm still fairly new to the SQL Syntax, so I'm not sure what is causing the issue. I think it's either something to do with the `ACId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,` or to do with the fact that one column is called "Comments", which could be mistaken for the SQL Data type `COMMENT`?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PlantAreaCode(
 ACId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 AreaCode INT,
 AreaName CHAR(25),
 Comments TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY (ACId);
```

Could someone also provide a good link to describe the SQL data type declarations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  have missed the closing bracket

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PlantAreaCode (
ACId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
AreaCode INT,
AreaName CHAR(25),
Comments TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (ACId)
);
```

[**See Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf26a)

Comment: +1 You beat me to it! :)

Comment: Ah! I completely missed that! Thankyou!

Comment: This link is also very useful, thanks for suggesting it :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed to close the brackets:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PlantAreaCode
(ACId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
AreaCode INT, 
AreaName CHAR(25), 
Comments TEXT, 
PRIMARY KEY (ACId)
);
```